# Teamcity automatic merge

Tags: teamcity

I'm trying to enable automatic merge branch "dev" after successful build to master. 
"Watch builds in branches" is set to: +:dev
"Merge into" is set to master. 
After build nothing happens.

Comment: Are the tests all running green?

Comment: Yes! There is no any message about failing anything

Comment: Might be worth getting in touch with JetBrains. They have a reasonable turnaround (took about two days to get back to me when I asked about Resharper recently).

Comment: I'll try when it will be sure that is their fault ;)

Comment: Having the same issue right now described at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30141426/teamcity-fails-to-merge-automatically . Maybe you have already found a workaround?

Comment: Sadly not yet. I'll write to support of teamcity.

Comment: @AndreyPesoshin I've created bug report, please vote on it:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-41012

Answer (score 1):

Those settings look correct...

When you say "After build nothing happens" what are you expecting? The UI will not display anything unless the automatic merge fails.

- Have you confirmed in your vcs that it hasn't merged?
- Are you sure the branch names are correct?
- Was the build successful?
- You can check the overview of a build that hasn't merged for a "Failed to merge sources..." message

Comment: For all questions answer is yes.

Comment: I'm expecting that it should merge master branch from current (dev) branch. There is no any message about failing anything. 
This Build configuration pull changes from dev branch and is running "grunt build" command, after that I want to merge to branch master

Comment: Do you mind adding screenshots of the build configuration and a build log of a build that didn't not merge?

Comment: Build Steps &  Build Feature screenshot

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do it the way suggested by @Andrey Pesoshin on [Teamcity fails to merge automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30141426/teamcity-fails-to-merge-automatically) . But it's not working fully the way I wanted to. 
Simpler is write merge script :/